# How to write an unsafepointer of type float in MPSImageDilate

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, metal, unsafe-pointers

I am new to Unsafepointer. In the following in this documentation, it says I need the values to be of type Unsafepointer. I need it to be equivalent of Array of 139*139 elements of repeatedValues of 1.0 (floating number).

```html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MetalPerformanceShaders/Reference/MPSImageDilate_ClassReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MPSImageDilate/initWithDevice:kernelWidth:kernelHeight:values:
```

Can someone provide me with ideas in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

In this case you'll be able to pass in a reference to the array (ie; a pointer to an existing array).

```
var dilateKernelValues = [Float](count:139*139, repeatedValue:1.0)

let dilateShader = MPSImageDilate(
    device: device, 
    kernelWidth:139, 
    kernelHeight:139, 
    values:&dilateKernelValues)
```

Comment: Sorry, was missing the `values` argument label. Code has now been updated, but I'm not sure this will help. Are you saying the code doesn't work (run and compile ok), or that the shader doesn't give you the results you are expecting? We'll probably need some more details, the kernel size does seem a little large to me, but I guess that depends on the image size and what you are trying to do.

Comment: When I try 139 * 139, I get "failed assertion `MPSImageDilate initWithDevice:kernelWidth:kernelHeight:values] kernel height too large.'". I can go up to 127 * 127 and the call works for me without the ampersand.

By the way, a probe containing all 1.0 will have no effect - set them all the zeros will give a rectangular dilation, in which case MPSImageAreaMax is a better bet.

Comment: Dilate is one of the most expensive filters in.MPS. Very large areas can result in the GPU being busy for a long time, causing frames to drop and possibly the GPU to restart, if the GPU mistakenly comes to mistakenly believe that it is hung.